# Pushing in github

Tags: git, cmd

This is my first time pushing in github and I must have typed in incorrectly for the first time because when I tried doing the steps again I get

`Fatal: remote origin already exists`

When I try to do a `>git push -u origin master`

I get an error saying:

> remote: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/gdguraido/angulartest.git/' not found

[image]

Looking at the image I made a wrong spelling in `gdguraido` it should be `gdguradio`

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the repository so what I did is change the repository like :

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/gdguradio/angulartest.git
```

Answer (score -3):

You could also edit `.git/config` file directly by any text editor.

```
nano .git/config
```